# Flyway: Can't insert the value NULL in 'installed_on', table 'schema_version' column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: sql, schema, h2, database-migration, flyway

Using Flyway-core:4.1.2 for database-migration.
 Added a new DDL file for flyway to execute. Flyway executes the DDL correctly and makes the corresponding changes to tables and columns. (We're adding a table and altering some previous columns in the new DDL). 
But, flyway fails to register this attempt to schema_version table: I get the following error:

> Current version of schema [dbo]: 2.1 
>   Unable to insert row for version '3.0' in metadata table [dbo].[schema_version]
>
> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
>   Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.FlywaySqlException:
>
> Message    : Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'installed_on', table 'dbo.schema_version'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Flyway successfully executes the DDL however, fails to logs it to the schema_version table due to NULL on installed_on. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. !

Comment: Did you find a fix for this @ASCIIbetical?

Comment: As a matter of fact I actually did. Thanks for checking in.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your fix, really appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah, actually sharing the fix would have been greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

In my case the error was that the database table `flyway_schema_history` had column `installed_on` defined like `DATETIME NOT NULL` while it should have been `DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL`.

The issue was resolved when I manually altered the column to include the default value definition.

My company has an number of databases which were created over a period of last 3 years, and i have noticed that the oldest and the youngest of them have the column set properly, while the ones from around 1.5 years have the column defined without the default. Perhaps it was a bug in some older versions of Flyway?